# how to use mongodb changeStream with c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to show last record in c# and for this target must know when new record insert to mongodb collection and update last record that show in c#. for this mongodb suggest use change stream but i can't use that.my code is below:

```
 namespace Kaa_app
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallMain(args).Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task CallMain(string[] args)
    {

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.43.267:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("kaa");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("endpoint");


        await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort("{_id:-1}").Limit(1).ForEachAsync(X => Console.WriteLine(X));

    }
    public class Data
    {
        [BsonId]
        public String application_id { get; set; }

        public String endpoint_id { get; set; }

        public String credentials_id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, in order to display the latest record in a collection, you don't need to use MongoDB change stream. You can just query the latest document sorted by `_id` as what you have done above. What's wrong with the code that you have ?

Comment: Yes I Know that. I connect a board with mongodb and it's clear that latest record update after board send new data to table and i want use best way that when I run program, after send new data I see latest data in my program without run it again. For this I want to use change stream .

Answer (score 6):

Below is an example code of how to open change stream with MongoDB using [MongoDB .Net/C# driver v2.7](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/). You may want to only listen for certain [change events](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-stream-output) i.e. inserts.

```
var database = client.GetDatabase("dbName");        
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collectionName");

var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>().Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'insert', 'delete' ] } }");

var cursor = collection.Watch<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>(pipeline, options);

var enumerator = cursor.ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument> doc = enumerator.Current;
    // Do something here with your document
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentKey); 
}
```

See also [Getting Stated with mongo-csharp-driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/getting_started/)

Comment: while(enumerator.MoveNext()) -> Does this run continuously in the loop ? I want to listen into changes through the day.

Comment: Yes, although you need to add some error handling in cases where it disconnects, etc.

Comment: Don't forget: var client = new MongoClient();